# Determine the indefinite integral $\int \frac{\sin x}{\sin 5x}dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

**Find the value of the given integral**

$$\int \frac{\sin x}{\sin 5x}dx$$

Answer (score 10):

HINT:

$$\sin(5x) =5\sin(x)-20\sin^3(x)+16\sin^5(x)$$

$$\frac{\sin x}{\sin5x}=\frac1{5-20\sin^2x+16\sin^4x}$$

$$=\frac{\csc^4x}{5\csc^4x-20\csc^2x+16}$$

$$=\frac{(1+\cot^2x)\csc^2x}{5(1+\cot^2x)^2-20(1+\cot^2x)+16}$$

Set $\cot x=u$

Comment: How to get the $sin(5x)$ identity?

Comment: @AriefAnbiya You can use https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html $$\sin5x-\sin3x=2\sin x\cos4x$$